# HTML tag inside label not showing

Tags: html

I have an UI element that shows when not being inside the label tag, when I put it inside the label or add a label before it won't show, what am I doing wrong?

As you can see with the first div only the text is shown, and with the 2nd div only the graphic is shown, I would like to have that toogle button with the text on the right side.

```css
#passwordToggleContainer {            
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;            
}

.password-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden; /* Hides the standard checkbox. */
}

.password-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.password-toggle + label:before,
.password-toggle + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

.password-toggle + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #66B650;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="passwordToggleContainer">

  <label>
    <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
    Set new password
  </label>
</div>

<div id="passwordToggleContainer">
  <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="setPasswordToggle">Set new password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that the input that is visible on your example is the input inside the label element. I'm wrong?

Comment: @RahulTripathi: he didn't. He put an `input` inside a `label`, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: @David With your edits it's starting to make more sense, OP.  Please make one more edit to ensure you don't have duplicate IDs.  (unless of course that's the problem with your code.  IDs need to be unique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a second label, since you are styling the first one.

```css
#passwordToggleContainer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}

.password-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden; /* Hides the standard checkbox. */
}

.password-toggle + label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 78px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.password-toggle + label:before,
.password-toggle + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

.password-toggle + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #66B650;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="passwordToggleContainer">
  <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="setPasswordToggle"></label>
  <label for="setPasswordToggle">Set new password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You gave me the right hint, since I am styling the first label I should use a second one for the text. To accept your answer please: remove display: flex; align-items: center;

Comment: And add vertical-align:middle; to .password-toggle + label, also change 50% by original 80%. With this you will get the text really beside the toggle button.

Comment: @David great, sorry my answer was rather short. Yea, it's better with verticle-align. Also, I didn't mention this but I also did change the width of the button from 80px to 78px. IMO it looks a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#passwordToggleContainer {            
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;            
}

.password-toggle {
  /*position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;*/ /* Hides the standard checkbox. */
}

.password-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.password-toggle + label:before,
.password-toggle + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

.password-toggle + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #66B650;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="passwordToggleContainer">

  <label>
    <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
    Set new password
  </label>
</div>

<div id="passwordToggleContainer">
  <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="setPasswordToggle">Set new password</label>
</div>
```

cause for First issue:
         You have added `position:absolute`. So both starts from the same location. So one hides another.

```css
#passwordToggleContainer {            
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;            
}

.password-toggle {
  /*position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;*/ /* Hides the standard checkbox. */
}

.password-toggle + label {
  /*display: block;*/
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.password-toggle + label:before,
.password-toggle + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

.password-toggle + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #66B650;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="passwordToggleContainer">

  <label>
    <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
    Set new password
  </label>
</div>

<div id="passwordToggleContainer">
  <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="setPasswordToggle">Set new password</label>
</div>
```

cause for Second issue:

You set display block to `both label and input` and `absolute position` to both.

Comment: But I don't want to show the checkbox, I want the toggle button with the text beside

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like this?

i placed the text "Set a new password" in a `div` of its own and applied a `margin-left` and `width` to it to get it to display to the right of the toggle img.

```css
#passwordToggleContainer {            
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;            
}

.password-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden; /* Hides the standard checkbox. */
}

.password-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.password-toggle + label:before,
.password-toggle + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

.password-toggle + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #66B650;
}

.password-toggle:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.instructions {
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="passwordToggleContainer">

  <label>
    <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
    Set new password
  </label>
</div>

<div id="passwordToggleContainer">
  <input id="setPasswordToggle" class="password-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="setPasswordToggle">
    <div class="instructions">
      Set new password
    </div> 
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks interesting, I must check what solution is the best, but I think this solution looks good!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did not accept this as the correct answer because the idea is to use labels so clicking on the text also clicks the toggle.

Comment: @David, ahh, sorry, your original post only posed the issue that the label was not showing on the right of the toggle and stated nothing about the actual toggle functionality.